# EXTJS : TreePanel click for set item change

Tags: extjs, treepanel

Hi everybody
I'm a beggining with extjs and I have issue with change / set a item to a layout when i click on one of my node .

Here my contentPanel :

```
var contentPanel = {
    id: 'content-panel',
    region: 'center', // this is what makes this panel into a region within the containing layout
    layout: 'card',
    margins: '2 5 5 0',
    activeItem: 0,
    border: false,
    items: layoutExamples // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE DYNAMIC
};
```

My "listener" on my treenode :

```
treePanel.getSelectionModel().on('select', function(selModel, record) {
    if (record.get('leaf')) {
        //Ext.getCmp('content-panel').layout.setActiveItem(record.getId() + '-panel'); <== It's work.
        Ext.getCmp('content-panel').setActive(formPanel); // HERE I TRY TO CHANGE ITEM ON CLICK AND SET FORMPANEL 

});
```

My item for test :

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    frame: true,
    title: 'Form Fields',
    width: 340,
    bodyPadding: 5,

    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'left',
        labelWidth: 90,
        anchor: '100%'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'textfield1',
        fieldLabel: 'Text field',
        value: 'Text field value'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'password1',
        inputType: 'password',
        fieldLabel: 'Password field'
    }, {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'file1',
        fieldLabel: 'File upload'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'textarea1',
        fieldLabel: 'TextArea',
        value: 'Textarea value'
    }   }]
});
```

So, my objective is to change item of my content panel when i click on a node.. !

Thanks a lot for your helps buddies !

Comment: where is defined formPanel ? Why don't you use the commented line if it works ?

Comment: FormPanel is defined onDocReady (if I do "items: formpanel" in contentPanel I have my item but it's static, I want to change on click (because I have many items, one by node)                     And the commented line is for change the layout (it's sencha sample), Me i just want to change the item..                                    Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that and tell me in the comments:

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',
    {
        'id': 'form-panel-1', // or what you want to give
        // and all the properties you already defined
    }
);
```

And in your event, based on http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.layout.container.Card-method-setActiveItem :

```
treePanel.getSelectionModel().on('select', function(selModel, record) {
    if (record.get('leaf')) {
        Ext.getCmp('content-panel').getLayout().setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('form-panel-1'));
    }
});
```

By the way, in the code you provided, there is an error in the listener, it misses a } for closing the if!

Comment: For the misses "}" yeah, juste a bad copy / paste .                                                             Unfortunely it's doesn't work :( . (Good try by the way...)               I also try id: 'form-panel-1' without quote for id  .             Thanks

Comment: Thanks it's work ! this too: Ext.getCmp('content-panel').layout.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('form-panel-1'));              But it's change the layout too. If nobody knows how to just change the "item" I will consider this answer :)

Comment: Maybe it's not how we call that method, but how you made the different panel (style, items included, border, etc?)

Comment: Yes I think  it's not the goodone, and I made the different panel like extjs example .